# Is that true that for every linear transformation $\phi : V^* \to W^*$ there is a linear transformation $\psi: W \to V$ such that $\psi^* = \phi$?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, dual-maps

$V$ and W are finitely dimensional linear spaces over the field $K$. Is that true that for every linear transformation $\phi : V^* \to W^*$ there is a linear transformation $\psi: W \to V$ such that $\psi^* = \phi$?

- W* means dual space of W, that is a space of all functionals $W \to K$
- V* means dual space of V, that is a space of all functionals $V \to K$

It is like an invert definition of dual mapping. It must be something simple, I just can't think of it anymore.

Comment: do you know about the relationship between a finite dimensional vector space and its second dual?

Comment: One way to answer this question is to choose bases for $V$ and $W$, write $\phi$ as a matrix with respect to the dual bases for $V^*$ and $W^*$, and $\psi$ as a matrix with respect to the bases of $V$ and $W$, and figure out how the two matrices are related if you assume $\psi^* = \phi$.

Comment: Are you sure? I've just read about sceond dual but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Deane, I think I can't choose basis for V and W because then I will just prove that equation for those basis in those dimensions. I could look for counterargument that way.

Comment: @mymathc, if you can work this out without making any assumptions about the dimensions, bases, and the map $\phi$, then it will be a proof.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true. You can consider the transpose map $\phi^*\colon W^{**}\to V^{**}$ and the canonical isomorphisms $\omega_W\colon W\to W^{**}$, $\omega_V\colon V\to V^{**}$.

Set $\psi=\omega_V^{-1}\circ\phi^*\circ\omega_W$ and finish up.